# From a host name, is there a way to find preferred protocol: HTTP or HTTPS?

Tags: sockets, https

I want to connect to some "domain.com" host provided by the user. I don't have the full URL like "http://domain.com". I don't know if "domain.com" supports SSL or not (it may be HTTPs-only or HTTP-only or support both, and HTTPS is preferred then). Is connecting to both https://domain.com and http://domain.com the only way to find out the correct protocol to be used for that host?

Ideally, I would like to examine, maybe, some DNS record for domain.com which lets me find out the preferred protocol instead of making two rather expensive network connections, HTTP and HTTPS (and one of them, if it's trying to connect to invalid port, may take a while to time out).

I have no direct control of "domain.com" hosts but I can suggest their owners to add DNS records or anything else if needed.

A particular programming language is not important at this point, I'm just curious about the concept in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to connect to some "domain.com" host provided by the user. I don't have the full URL like "http://domain.com". I don't know if "domain.com" supports SSL or not (it may be HTTPs-only or HTTP-only or support both, and HTTPS is preferred then). Is connecting to both https://domain.com and http://domain.com the only way to find out the correct protocol to be used for that host?

Usually, yes.  Or at least the simplest way.

A domain name by itself can typically only be resolved to an IP address.  You don't know what is actually running at that IP address.  It might have an HTTP server, an HTTPS server, an FTP server, SMTP/POP servers, and IMAP server, etc.  You just don't know what is available until you actually try to connect to it with your chosen protocol.

So, you would have to attempt to connect with HTTP and HTTPS separately, and whichever one succeeds is the winner.

> Ideally, I would like to examine, maybe, some DNS record for domain.com which lets me find out the preferred protocol instead of making two rather expensive network connections, HTTP and HTTPS

There is a standard DNS [SRV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2782) record that *could* be used to provide information about the presence of an HTTP/HTTPS server and the port number it is running on (this type of usage is covered in [Use of SRV records in conjuction with HTTP and URIs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-andrews-http-srv-02), which is expired).

There is also a standard DNS [URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7553) record type that also can provide a mapping between a service name and a URI describing the protocol and port used for that service.

However, most admins don't use `SRV`/`URI` records to describe HTTP/S servers (for example, Google and Yahoo do not), so this would have to be something extra you request from your customers, and not something you can rely on for all domains the user may give you.

> and one of them, if it's trying to connect to invalid port, may take a while to time out

You can implement your own timeout on an outgoing connection, you are not limited to the OS's default timeout.

Answer (score 2):

I think connecting to the actual sites may be a necessity to determine which endpoint is canonical as

1. you'd only know if a site is up when you connect to it and
2. you'd only know about any redirects after you connect.

Take a look at these two Python projects - [benbalter/site-inspector](https://github.com/benbalter/site-inspector) and [dhs-ncats/pshtt](https://github.com/dhs-ncats/pshtt). They use a combination of connection statuses, HTTP response codes and redirects to determine the canonical endpoint for a given domain.